# Unity - raycast is clearly colliding but does not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Ok I have 2 objects on the Default layer that I need to trigger a jump with when raycast collides. I can see that the raycast is intersecting the platform:

[image]

And here is my collider on the platform:

[image]

And yet nothing is printed with:

```
Vector3 rotation = transform.forward;

        RaycastHit hit;
        Debug.DrawRay(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.4f, transform.position.z), rotation, Color.green);
        if (Physics.Raycast(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.4f, transform.position.z), rotation, out hit, rayDistance))
        {
            print(hit.transform);
            if (hit.transform.GetComponent<Platform>() != null)
            {
                Jump(hit.transform);
            }
        }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is `rayDistance`?

Comment: The length of your `Debug.DrawRay` isn't necessarily the same as your `Physics.RayCast`. Make sure they are actually colliding

Comment: @Savaria what do you mean? How can I see what the actual raycast is or if they are colliding?

Comment: @Immersive 1.2f

Comment: The length of your ray is stored in different variables in the two functions. In `Physics.Raycast` it's in the maxDistance. In `Debug.DrawRay` it's the length of the direction vector.

Comment: @Savaria whats an example of the Raycast line written correctly?

Comment: Yours is written correctly. But in `Debug.DrawRay` you should normalize the rotation and multiply it by your rayDistance to make sure they have the same length

Comment: @Savaria when I do this there's no ray? Why would that be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189715/discussion-between-savaria-and-userdude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code adapted from [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html](https://i.imgur.com/OcATHL3.gifv) using your values:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 startPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.4f, transform.position.z);
if (Physics.Raycast(startPoint, rotation, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
{
    Debug.DrawRay(startPoint, rotation * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
    Debug.Log("Did Hit");
}
else
{
    Debug.DrawRay(startPoint, rotation * 1000, Color.white);
    Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
}
```

Here it is a [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/OcATHL3.gifv) from a test I did.

This is just a test to see if the problem is the difference between ray distances.

You may also use Debug.DrawLine instead and then set up the end point with the same distance used in the RayCast.

```
Vector3 startPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.4f, transform.position.z);
if (Physics.Raycast(startPoint, rotation, out hit, rayDistance))
{
    Debug.DrawLine(startPoint, startPoint + rotation * rayDistance, Color.green);
}
else Debug.DrawLine(startPoint, startPoint + rotation * rayDistance, Color.red);
```

Another [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/Qig7125.gifv) using this code.

If it still doesn't work, try checking out the matrix collision.

Don't forget that you may also use a layermask in your raycast. :)